# Qt Creator autocomplete with cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

In Qt Creator, I have removed the qmake step, and added my own cmake step, with a CMakeLists.txt file. Now, for any classes I have defined internally in my project, autocomplete works. For example, class names for my custom classes are displayed in a different colour, and when I hover over a variable it gives me details on that variable.

However, for any third-party libraries I am using in my project, autocomplete does not work. The classes are displayed in the standard white colour, and nothing appears when I hover over a variable from this library. But the libraries are defined correctly in CMakeLists.txt, and my program compiles and runs fine. So, Qt Creator eventually can find the libraries, but it cannot do so during code editing for autocomplete to work. What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, it worked for me.

1. open a c++ file in which you want to do auto-complete.
2. go to "tool -> c++ -> inspect c++ code model"
3. in the pop up you will see the unresolved file in red under "snapshot and documents & documents -> includes"
4. manually locate the folder that contains these files
5. in project view on the left panned, locate "[project name].include" file
6. add in the directories that contains the unresolved files and save
   now you should have the auto-complete working.

It seems to me that qt-creators build in code model does not take the include path from cmake, but rely on the file that itself created.